# Google Places API sorting by radius or distance

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-places-api

I'm building JS app.Tasks are:
1.Locate me and find nearest ATMs of specified bank
2.Then sort what she found in list.Sort by distance from me.
3.On the end are some design like a image on marker of store etc..

Well I did to locate me and to show me locations of ATMs 
But I can't figure out to create list and sort that ATMs by distance from me

Does someone can help me

My code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place searches</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var map;
      var infowindow;

      function initMap() {
        var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: pyrmont,
          zoom: 15
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: pyrmont,
          radius: 500,
          type: ['store']
        }, callback);
      }

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
          }
        }
      }

      function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCW8gRR1ITJDx4F-rVpkBSetftu32XO2P0&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like `results` in your `callback` funciton are the ATMs you are searching for? Perhaps you can do a potential `sort` on that? It would be easier to help you if you had a working example.

Comment: Oh sorry about that.This is the code which show ATMs around specified location

I will show you

Comment: this is a code 
show ATMs of specified bank
I can't figure to mark with marker my location
Well how I can now create list to sort the nearest ATMs by distance from me(first 10)

https://jsfiddle.net/vhcn6g1L/